# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am unsure of what this error means "run: line 1:3 Segmentation fault(core dumped) ./a.out" since this is the first time I have encountered it. It seems the error is happening here

```
dgemm(40, &A, &B, &C);
```

This is my code

```
void dgemm (int n, double *A, double *B, double *C) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            double cij = C[i + j * n];
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                cij += A[i + k * n] * B[k + j * n];
            }
            C[i + j * n] = cij;
        }
    }
}

int main() { 
    double A = 4.1;
    double B = 5.2;
    double C = 7.4;
    
    dgemm(40, &A, &B, &C);
    return 0;
}
```

can anyone tell me what is causing this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Does [this](https://godbolt.org/z/8KPGG8P1n) solve the mystery?

Comment: 1) A  "segmentation fault" is a runtime error, not a "compile-error" (per your original tag).  2) More to the point ... if dgemm() treats input parameters A, B and C as "40-element arrays" ...then you'd gosh darn better allocate space for 40 elements!  Passing "addressof" a single double instead of allocating space for an n-element array is pretty much guaranteed to cause a segmentation error!

Comment: It actually treats them as 1600-element arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A, B, and C aren't arrays, they're scalars. When you access them as arrays you're accessing invalid memory, which is undefined behavior. If you want arrays, you could do:

```
double A[1600];
double B[1600];
double C[1600];
```

If you don't know the size of N at compile-time, allocate the arrays on the heap:`double *A = malloc(n * n * sizeof (double));`

Be sure to `free(A)` when done.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
               cij += A[i+k*n] * B[k+j*n];
         C[i+j*n] = cij;
```

Is buggy.  Because you are passing a pointer to a **single** instance of a double for all three variables: `A`, `B`, and `C`.  But you are accessing each as if they were an array within your function.  Any index other than `0` is invalid until you allocate an array of proper size.